# Childrens Anthology with the first chapter of the Hobbit and a Moomintroll story

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book, fairy-tales

I read *The Hobbit* in 1963 after reading a large format children's illustrated anthology which  had a Tove Jansson Moomintroll story or chapter and the first chapter of *The Hobbit* along with other stories I don't remember.

Thus this anthology would have been published in 1963 or earlier.

Several years ago I managed to identify this anthology somehow on the internet.  I believe there were several editions published under various titles in the 1950s and 60s.

But now I don't remember the title of that anthology.

I just now looked up J.R.R. Tolkien at the Internet Speculative Fiction Database and couldn't find any record of the first chapter of *The Hobbit* appearing in an anthology.

[https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?302[1]](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?302%5B1%5D)

I also looked up Tove jansson there: [https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?2148[2]](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?2148%5B2%5D)

and the only anthology listed with a Moomin story was this one:

[https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?297476[3]](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?297476%5B3%5D)

And it includes stories published long after 1963 and nothing by Tolkien.

So I wonder if anyone is familiar with that anthology.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This could be [**The Golden Treasury of Children's Literature**](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/461097.The_Golden_Treasury_Of_Children_s_Literature), first published in 1947 by Bryna and Louis Untermeyer, with various editions and volumes published since then.

According to [this link](https://www.etsy.com/au/listing/597460096/wonder-land-the-golden-treasury-of), volume 5 "Wonder Lands" contains an excerpt from "The Hobbit" and "The Happy Moomins" by Jansson.

[image]

Comment: Great find! Excellent chance this is it.

Comment: Yes, I think this is it.  Thank you, Moriarty.  See here: http://mythoi.tolkienindex.net/#post7  and see here: http://tolkienandfantasy.blogspot.com/2012/

Answer (score 6):

A WorldCat search for a book with both Jansson and Tolkien in the author credits identifies **[*Children's classics to read aloud*](https://www.worldcat.org/title/childrens-classics-to-read-aloud/oclc/26314102)**, published in 1992.

The contents include; ***Under the hill*** (from *The Hobbit* by J.R.R. Tolkien) and
***Invisible Child*** (from *Tales from the Moomin Valley* by Tove Jansson).

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This seems like it might actually be a correct answer to the question, but it's really hard to read.  You should put the title in bold at the top, followed by the details of the Tolkien and Jansson stories.

Comment: @DavidW - Or you could [edit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/210732/edit) the answer for them to show them how it's done!

Comment: Except for "thus this anthology would have been published in 1963 or earlier."

Comment: @OrganicMarble - OPs are often confused about the date.

Comment: @Valorum I've told you before, you're just too fast for me to keep up with. :)

Comment: @DavidW - [Too slow, G.I. Joe!](https://data.whicdn.com/images/253542921/original.gif)

Comment: @Valorum  I am quite certain that I read the anthology I asked about, and then read the Hobbit to find out what happened after the first chapter, and then several years later I read the Fellowship of the Rings on July 4 to 5, 1966.  Thus the earliest publication of the anthology in question must have been at least 26 years before 1992, the earliest publication date for Children's Classics to Read Aloud that has been found so far.